# Make Google Map V2 in full screen of Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

i put Google Map in fragment and all of this in Relative layout

but when make padding |left |Right |Top   to map  ,

the map don't stretches to whole screen and take constant size with no change  as photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdCl.jpg

i wanna to make as this photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yndIu.jpg

Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ebebeb"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/belowlayout"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/belowlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"

        android:onClick="NextActivity"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove this

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from your parent `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove padding from   `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#ebebeb"
 >
```